# scrolling a div of images horizontally with controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with a bunch of images in it.  With arrow controls to the left and right.  I want my div to scroll right and left through the images with the arrow controls. I can find vertically scrolling a div up and down but now left and right?

Comment: Check out this jquery plugin called jcarousel http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Answer (score 9):

You can scroll left and right when clicking on your arrows by editing the `scrollLeft` DOM property of the scrolling element.

Using jQuery, you can use the `.scrollLeft()` function to get or set the `scrollLeft` property - [link to docs](https://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)

Here is a really simple page I just cooked up that shows the behavior:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function scrollDiv(dir, px) {
        var scroller = document.getElementById('scroller');
        if (dir == 'l') {
            scroller.scrollLeft -= px;
        }
        else if (dir == 'r') {
            scroller.scrollLeft += px;
        }
    }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #scroller {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        overflow: scroll;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #inner-scroller {
        width: 800px;
        height: 800px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body style="text-align: center;">

<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="scrollDiv('l', 20); return false;">scroll left</a>
|
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="scrollDiv('r', 20); return false;"> scroll right</a>

<div id="scroller">
    <div id="inner-scroller">
        800x800
    </div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```