# Smooth JavaScript horizontal scroll in DIV

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have content in a horizontal div that exceeds the page area so that to see all of it you have to scroll horizontally. Fine with a trackpad but for those who don't have one I want to make this obvious with the use of either scrollbars or mouseover text/image.

After hours of experiments I finally found this code - [scrolling a div of images horizontally with controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414304/scrolling-a-div-of-images-horizontally-with-controlls) - which is perfect(just changed it to mouseover).

The only problem is I want to do it smoothly and without having to repeat the mouseover or clicking.

Also I want to avoid Jquery and all that sliders stuff. I'm a very new to JS and want to keep things simple. Also I wasn't able to force a scrollbar with any CSS solutions.

Thank you

Comment: jQuery is meant to make JS simple...

Comment: Show us some examples of code you have tried.

Comment: Ok but I don't understand anything of Jquery. Whereas the script I have linked to I can just about decipher. Just don't understand how to affect its behaviour.

Comment: I tried this http://www.dyn-web.com/code/scroll/horiz.php based on a link here. Don't understand how to implement it.

Comment: And of course the one I linked to