# Scroll left / right an image with animation

Tags: javascript, html, image, scroll

Please take a look at this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XV9P6/5/)**.

By using the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5414462/1581050) I've managed to make the image to move horizontally  by clicking the left or right links.

What I'd like to achieve is to make the image jumps smoother somehow.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    var scrollDiv = function(dir, px) {
        var scroller = document.getElementById('scroller');
        if (dir == 'l'){
            scroller.scrollLeft -= px;
        }
        else if (dir == 'r'){
            scroller.scrollLeft += px;
        }
    }
</script>

<a class="tArrowL" href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="scrollDiv('l', 80); return false;">« left</a>
<a class="tArrowR" href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="scrollDiv('r', 80); return false;">right »</a>
<div class="wrapOut">
    <div id="scroller" class="wrapIn">
        <img id="" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1044-480-2.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use the `animate` function, but with no success:

```
var scrollDiv = function(dir, px) {
    var scroller = document.getElementById('scroller');
    if (dir == 'l'){
        scroller.animate( { scrollLeft: '-= px' }, 1000);
    }
    else if (dir == 'r'){
        scroller.animate( { scrollLeft: '+= px' }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I'm testing on IE 10 on windows 8 on touchscreen desktop, so it has to work on swipe / tap events too.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XV9P6/6/)**

You need to animate the `scrollLeft` property of the **jQuery object `scroller`**, and not the **HTMLObject `scroller`**, because it's the former which has the method `animate`.

```
var scrollDiv = function (dir, px) {
    var scroller = document.getElementById('scroller'), // HTMLObject
        go;   // holds '+=' or '-='

    if (dir == 'l') go = '-=';
     else go = '+=';     // no need for else-if here

    // `$(HTMLObject)` ---> `jQuery Object`
    $(scroller).animate({
        scrollLeft: go + px  // becomes '-=int' or '+=int' 
    }, 500); // duration
}
```