# Scrolling left and right javascript

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I'm trying to make a custom slider for my google map and am needing to slide the content left and right via my buttons see [here](http://www.northerntechnomics.com/lmantzel/googlemap/maptest12.html#) for clearer view if what I'm trying to do.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063870/scroll-left-right-an-image-with-animation) has the right idea of what I want to do but I cannot get it to work properly.

Even a basic example on how to make a div, with divs inside of it, that slides left and right would be a huge help. So far most examples are images or one image and I cannot seem to get them implemented for my purposes. Thanks in advance.

-L

Comment: I don't have any code to show because I tried 6-8 different things from examples online but none of them work. Not one of the situations are exactly what I am doing with divs inside of a div. They all use pictures or divs that scroll up and down. There is no example of this online that I have found so I am not sure that I even have the right idea with any of the things I tried. The linked post does what I want over one image. I tried implementing that code into my app and nothing happened and no errors were thrown. I just really need help understanding how to scroll/animate a div left and righ

Comment: This comment was not helpful at all. Please see answer below for solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working almost completely the way I want. For anyone else trying to scroll left and right here is a working example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linddss/q4haaey6/).

JQuery:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
          $('#sliderWrapper').animate({
            marginLeft: "-=200px"
          }, "fast");
       });
$('#prev').click(function() {
      $('#sliderWrapper').animate({
        marginLeft: "+=200px"
      }, "fast");
   });
```